# how to copy a folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I need a function that lets me copy a folder and what is in the folder into another existing folder. I have tried "shutil.copy", "shutil.copy2" and shutil.copytree" none of these do what I want. I am on python 3.6.2 on windows 10. I am still learning this language so don't make the explanations to complicated.

Comment: It might help if you explained what the functions you mentioned lack that you're looking for.

Comment: sure, copy 1 and two only copy a specific file. i want to copy the hole folder. copy tree copys the hole directory and I just want one folder and in copy tree one of the directories can not already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something:

```
import os

def copyfolder(folder,newfolder):
    os.system("xcopy \""+folder+"\" \""+newfolder+"\" /h /i /c /k /e /r /y")
```

Comment: would this work if i am just trying to copy a folder and what it contains in to an existing folder.

Comment: @JacobKnuth I believe so.

Comment: i get "Invalid number of parameters"

Comment: def copyfolder(folder,newfolder):
    os.system("xcopy  "+folder+" "+newfolder+" /e /i /h")

copyfolder("C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/New folder", "C:/Users/jacob/Pictures/Camera Roll")

Comment: @JacobKnuth I've edited the post, try it with the new edit.

Comment: I just plugged the 2 folders in to the function

Comment: still invalid parameters

Comment: this is what I did

Comment: def copyfolder(folder,newfolder):
    os.system("xcopy "+folder+" "+newfolder+" /h /i /c /k /e /r /y")

copyfolder("C:/Users/jacob/Desktop/New folder", "C:/Users/jacob/Pictures/Camera Roll")

Comment: @JacobKnuth that's odd

Comment: there is no built in function that would copy a whole folder?

Comment: @JacobKnuth no there isn't but I think I know the problem, let me edit

Comment: @JacobKnuth No problem. The problem was the fact that you have a space in your directory, so It needs quotes or it will think it is a seperate directory after the space.